# Integral Representation for the product of Modified Bessel Functions

Tags: improper-integrals, bessel-functions

On page 140 of *Special Functions and Their Applications* by N. N. Lebedev, we are asked to derive the following two integral representations:

$$\tag{1}K_{\nu }(x) K_{\nu
   }(y)=\frac{1}{2} (\pi  \csc
   (\nu  \pi )) \int_{\log
   \left(\frac{y}{x}\right)}^{
   \infty } J_0\left(\sqrt{2 x
   y \cosh (t)-x^2-y^2}\right)
   \sinh (\nu  t) \, dt,$$ $x>0$, $y>0$, $| \Re(\nu )| <\frac{1}{4}$
and

$$\tag{2}I_{\nu }(x) K_{\nu
   }(y)=\frac{1}{2} \int_{\log
   \left(\frac{y}{x}\right)}^{
   \infty } J_0\left(\sqrt{2 x
   y \cosh (t)-x^2-y^2}\right)
   e^{-\nu  t} \, dt ,$$ $x>0$, $y>0$, $\Re(\nu )>-\frac{1}{4}$.

Here $K_{\nu }(z)$,$I_{\nu }(z)$ are the Macdonald function and the modified Bessel function of the first kind respectively and $J_0(z)$ is the Bessel function of the first kind of order $0$.

A more general form of these two results (Bessel functions of different order) can be found in the paper: Integrals for the Product of two Bessel Functions (II), Dixon & Ferrar, *The Quarterly Journal of Mathematics*, Vol. OS-4, Issue 1, 1933, pp. 297-304. Is there a simpler derivation available for the special cases given above?